# Find $M$ such that $A=M B M^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two square matrices $A$ and $B$ of only zeros and ones, can we find matrix $M$ in polynomial time, such that $A = M B M^T$ ?

The matrix $M$ is a **permutation matrix**, that is, it has in each row and column only one occurrence of one and the rest are zeros.

The transpose of a permutation matrix is equal to its inverse. Therefore, $A = MBM^{T} = MBM^{-1}$

Comment: Your $M$ will be a permutation matrix. Therefore the equation is insolvable at least when $A$ and $B$ are not similar.

Comment: Thanks much for the comment. Could you give some suggestions to read about it? I am wondering why it is insolvable.

Comment: $M$ is a permutation matrix. Therefore $M^T=M^{-1}$. Thus the equation $A=MBM^T$ implies that $A=MBM^{-1}$, i.e. if the equation is solvable, $A$ and $B$ are necessarily similar.

Comment: Thanks much for clarification. So if $A$ and $B$ are similar, and $A=MBM^{-1}$, then can we find $M$ in polynomial time, if $M$ exists?

Comment: Huh? No. Similarity is only a necessary condition, not a sufficient condition. E.g. even though $A=\pmatrix{0&0&1\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&0&0}$ is similar to $B=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&0&0}$, there isn't any permutation matrix $M$ that makes $A=MBM^T$ because $A$ and $B$ have different number of ones.

Comment: If it is known that $M$ exists, then I believe that finding the permutation matrix $M$ is equivalent to solving the [graph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem)

Comment: Sure. It is equivalent to solving the graph isomorphism problem. But it is not known if graph isomorphism problem is solvable in polynomial time.

Comment: @rsh Well if you agree with my statement, then you have your answer. "Is there a way to find a matrix $M$, assuming one exists"?  Yes, and it is not known whether the problem is solvable in polynomial time

Comment: Thanks. Correct. Do you have any suggestion to go further and tackle this problem: "whether this equation is solvable in polynomial time"?

Answer (score 1):

Equation

$$A=MBM^T=MBM^{-1}\tag{1}$$

implies, taking determinants, that

$$\det(A)=\det(B)\det(M)^2.\tag{2}$$

Matrix $M$, being a permutation matrix is orthogonal, therefore has $\det(M)=\pm 1$.

As a consequence, unless

$$\det(A)=\det(B)\tag{3}$$

(necessary condition), there is no hope that such a matrix $M$ exists.

Is  (3) a sufficient condition ? No, here is a counterexample,

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix} \ and \ B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\tag{4}$$

(consider eigenvalues : they are not the same).

**Remark :** more generally, if we restrict our attention to matrices $A$ and $B$ which are themselves permutation matrices (as is the case for (4)), a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of such an $M$ is that they have the same **cycle structure** (for example (ab)(cde) and (ace)(db)). On the algorithmic point of view, it is not time consuming !

**Edit :** Here is a good general [question/answers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/291330) about this issue.

Comment: Thanks much for the answer. But if we know that $det(A)=det(B)$, then how could we solve it?

Comment: Take care : $\det(A)=\det(B)$ is a necessary condition. I am almost certain that it is not a sufficient condition.

Comment: Thanks much for the comment. Could you give some suggestions to read about it? I am trying to get a better understanding of the problem. Yes, we do not know if $M$ exists, but if it exists, then the question is whether we can find it in polynomial time.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. There is another comment about the equivalence of this problem with graph isomorphism problem. It is not known whether graph isomorphism problem is solvable in polynomial time. Do you have any suggestion to go further and tackle this problem?

Comment: graph isomorphism sounds like a generalisation of the "cycle structure" I mention in my remark (with for example, the "supports" of the different cycles being in correspondence with connected components...

Comment: Thanks. Could you suggest an article or a book so that I can study more about it?

Comment: About the graph isomorphism problem, you surely have see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem). Take a look at [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/291330).